# JQuery if statement based on width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a menu that opens and closes slightly.

If the menu is 20% wide, I want the items to show. If the menu is 10% wide, I want the items to be hidden. A menu button is used to expand and collapse the menu. I can get the menu collapsing but I try to add anything that expands the menu based on the width it breaks.

```
$(".icon-menu").click(function() {
                $(".sidebar").animate({
                    width: "10%",
                }, 200 );
                $(".sidebar ul").css("display", "none"),
                $(".menu-heading").css("display", "none");
            });
            if (".sidebar").css("width") == "10%"{
            $(".icon-menu").click(function() {
                $(".sidebar").animate({
                    width: "20%",
                }, 200 );
                $(".sidebar ul").css("display", "visible"),
                $(".menu-heading").css("display", "visible");
            });
```

Comment: Your line `if (".sidebar").css("width") == "10%"` is not proper JavaScript to begin with and you wanna have 1 `click` function that checks the width rather than different click functions depending on the width.

Comment: @funkwurm I'm not sure of the proper way to handle that then. So something like click -> if div = 10% do this, else if div = 20% do that?

Comment: Yup, that sounds like an approach that could work :) And I'll give you another hint, the condition needs to be surrounded by parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you've got 2 click events bound to `$('.icon-menu')` if the width is 10%.
Also, 'visible' isn't a valid option for the CSS element [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) - I believe in your instance, you're wanting 'block' .

Here's the code, slightly re-factored:

```
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {

    var $sidebar = $('.sidebar'),
        show_menu = $sidebar.css('width') == '10%';

    $sidebar.animate({
        width: show_menu ? '20%' : '10%'
    }, 200);

    if(show_menu) {

        $sidebar.find('ul').css('display', 'block'),
        $('.menu-heading').css('display', 'block');

    } else {

        $sidebar.find('ul').css('display', 'none'),
        $('.menu-heading').css('display', 'none');

    }

});
```

Comment: Works to collapse but not expand the menu back out again. I don't understand jQuery well enough to really get whats going on here.

Comment: Your code will not working because you're trying get percentage value with `css('width')`. css('width') returns computed width, e.g. `400px` (with `px`). Best way is get width with `width()` (will return just number, without `px`), get parent width, compute percentage and use this percentage.

Comment: I mean, 'best way if you want use "percentage" method'.

Answer (score 0):

**What if the width didn't matter, but you could achieve the same thing?**

might make more sense if you change the jquery to something like this

```
$(".icon-menu").parent().addClass('out').end().on('click', function () {
    var menu = $(this).parent();
    if (menu.hasClass('out')) {
        menu.removeClass('out').animate({marginRight: '-10%'},200).children('.menu-heading, ul').fadeTo(200,0);
    } else {
       menu.addClass('out').animate({marginRight: '0%'},500).children('.menu-heading, ul').fadeTo(200,1);
    }
});
```

I made a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/fXHtt/